# deleteCell doesn't work with directly selected trs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a tr directly and dynamically.
the tr is selected or so I think , but when I'm applying the deleteCell method it saysthat the object doesn't have such method! 
a portion of the code :

```
set: function(f, res){
        var row = $('tr#moRow'+f), arr = res.split('|'), cell,
        links = new Array(
            'forums.php?f='+f+'&option=mo',
            'forums.php?f='+f+'&option=ho',
            'forums.php?f='+f+'&option=rmo',
            'forums.php?f='+f+'&option=rho',
            'pm.php?mail=new&f=-'+f
        );
        if(row){
        alert(row);// gives [object object]
            row.deleteCell(1);
            for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
                cell = row.insertCell(x + 1);
                cell.className = (arr[x] > 0 ? 'asFirstB' : 'asNormalB')+' asCenter';
                cell.innerHTML = (arr[x] > 0) ? "<a href=\""+links[x]+"\"><b>"+arr[x]+"</b></a>" : "0";
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use native JS functions on an element, you need to address the DOM element instead of the jQuery one.

```
row[0].deleteCell(1);
```